# how to get the hash value when using StaticWordValueEncoder in Mahout

Tags: mahout

I'm look at an example in the Mahout in Action book. It uses the StaticWordValueEncoder to encoder a text in the feature hashing manner.
When encode "text to magically vectorize" with a standard analyser and probe = 1, the vector is {12:1.0, 54:1.0, 78:1.0}. However, I can't figure out which word the hash index refers to.
Is there any method to get the [hash, original word] as a pair? e.g. hash 12 refers to the word "text"?

Answer (score 0):

if you have read  Mahout in Action paragraph:

"The value of a continuous 
variable gets added directly to **one or more locations** that are allocated for the storage
of the value. The location or locations are determined by the name of the feature.

This hashed feature approach has the distinct advantage of requiring less memory
and one less pass through the training data, but it can make it **much harder to reverse engineer
vectors to determine which original feature mapped to a vector location**."

-----I am not sure how the reverse engineering can be done(which certainly a difficult task as Author has put) Perhaps some one might put some light on this.